# Is the story of 1000 people of ibn ubayy's tribe after his funeral due to the prophet's (pbuh) good conduct converting to islam authentic?

Tags: authenticity

I came across something which goes like

“My shirt and the janazah prayer I performed will not save him from the torture of my Lord. However, I hope that one thousand people from his tribe will become sincere Muslims thanks to them.”[9]

Indeed, one thousand people became Muslims when they saw that the Messenger of God treated Abdullah b. Ubay so graciously.[10]

The sources for his are
[9]Tabari, Tafsir, Vol. 10, 206.

[10]Ayni, Umdatu’l-Qari, Vol. 8, p. 54.

Do both have an isnad and are they authentic? Thank you very much